# Placeholder when using minimum length

Tags: tom-select

I'm using the shouldLoad functionality to set a minimum length of characters before data loads from a remote source, like the example [here](https://jsfiddle.net/jy4vhnr5/)

```
shouldLoad:function(query){
        if ( query.length < 3 ) return false;
  return true;
},
```

Is there a way to show the user that they must then enter this minimum number of characters, like select2 does?

[image]

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course,

You can use `not_loading` in your renderer function which is triggered when you return false from `shouldLoad`.

Example:

```
render: {       
            option: function(item, escape) {
                return `<div>${ escape(item.name) }</div>`;
            },
            item: function(item, escape) {
                return `<div>${ escape(item.name) }</div>`;
            },
            not_loading:function(data,escape){
                return `<div>Please enter 2 or more characters </div>`;
            },
        },
    });
```

You can learn more from their official [doc](https://tom-select.js.org/docs/).

Hope it helps.